# Why does excel SUMIF function give wrong figure?

Tags: excel, office365

[image]

Taking sum of HP. But my formula is providing me wrong amount despite of criteria not being fulfilled!

Comment: `=SUMIF(CN_2021[HP],$P14,CN_2021[Sum of ORDER_QTY])`

Comment: You may also try using `SUMPRODUCT` --> `=SUMPRODUCT(($P14=CN_2021[HP])*(CN_2021[SUM OF ORDER_QTY]))` , `SUMIF` also works

Comment: This helped! Thanks!
Can you please tell me why my formula wasn't working? Or what was the mistake in my formula?

Comment: @Sridevi place both the formulas, and compare, you shall know on your own, its self explanatory, you were not selecting the proper ranges or the arguments, you had selected the whole table as a criteria range and same goes for the other arguments as well.

Comment: You were using a `range` parameter of `CN_2021[[#All],[HP]:[Sum of ORDER_AMT]]`, which is a reference to the entire table (including headers), so you were searching for the value in `P14` in all three columns, not just the first.

Comment: @Sridevi please go through the documentation for `SUMIF` from Microsoft that should help you to understand how to apply a SUMIF Function --> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: Please add your formula to the question, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Understood, thank you @JosWoolley

Comment: Will keep in mind next time! @SJR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's worth posting an explanation as to why your original formula does not work, as it highlights an interesting feature of the function `SUMIF`.

As stated in one of my commments, you are passing a `range` parameter to that function of `CN_2021[[#All],[HP]:[Sum of ORDER_AMT]]`, which is a reference to the entire table (including headers). Hence, you are effectively searching for the entry from `P14` in **all three columns**, not just the first.

However, you are also using a `sum_range` parameter of `CN_2021[[#All],[Sum of ORDER_QTY]]`, which is only one column. One might think that the construction should **flat out error**, since your `range` and `sum_range` parameters are not of an equal dimension (the former comprises 3 columns, the latter only 1).

The reason it does not error is due to the fact that, in such cases, Excel **redimensions** the `sum_range` so as to be of an equal dimension to the `range`.

So, if we replace the Table references with their equivalent worksheet references (assuming that table begins in `A3`) for the sake of simplification, we have that

`=SUMIF(CN_2021[[#All],[HP]:[Sum of ORDER_AMT]],P14,CN_2021[[#All],[Sum of ORDER_QTY]])`

which is equivalent to

`=SUMIF(A3:C19,P14,B3:B19)`

*should* error, though the single-column range

`B3:B19`

is redimensioned to a three-column range in line with the `range`, i.e.

`B3:D19`

which means that you are effectively performing

`=SUMIF(A3:C19,P14,B3:D19)`

This could have potential consequences were column D also populated: for example, place a 3 in cell `C14` and 1000 in cell `D14`. The formula will now pick up this extra 1000 in the sum.

Strangely, unlike `SUMIF`, `SUMIFS` does not appear to be so lenient with respect to this redimensioning:

`=SUMIFS(B3:B19,A3:C19,P14)`

errors.